# Jenkins Pipeline Access stage steps variable in power shell execution

Tags: shell, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to access normal variable defined in my steps into power shell execution.
We can access environment variables using $env but, how to access normal step variables?

```
stages {
        stage ('sometask') {
                steps{
                     script {
                        def someString = 'Hi'
                        withCredentials(...) {
                        def out = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 
                               '''
                               // Access someString 
                         ''')
                         println out
                       }
                }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't probably the most elegant way to do it but I've done it like this:
(I will use your same example)

```
stages {
        stage ('sometask') {
                steps{
                     script {
                        def someString = 'Hi'
                        withCredentials(...) {
                        def out = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 
                               '''
                        PowerShellCommands.... 
                        Write-Host ''' + someString + '''
                        someMorePowerShellCommands
                         ''')
                         println out
                       }
                }
```

So basically what I'm doing is concatenating the value of

> someString

In the middle of the script, if you would for instance need to pass more variables you need to follow the same logic:

```
''' some script code ''' + variableName + 
''' some more script code''' + anotherVariableName + 
''' evenMoreScriptCode '''
```

In my case I am using config parameters and instead of the

> variableName

I am using

> config.webURL

for instance.

Hope this helps.

EN

Answer (score 0):

Following should work :)

stages {

```
    stage ('sometask') {
            steps{
                 script {
                    def someString = 'Hi'
                    withCredentials(...) {
                    def out = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 
                           """
                           // Accessing someString 
                           Write-Host $someString
                     """)
                     println out
                   }
            }
     }
```

}